# Running a .el file when opening emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I downloaded two .el files
One is to highlight current column where cursor is and another one to highlight some specific words.
I followed next steps in the file:

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.xemacs/packages/")` //path where I saved .el files

`(load "column-marker")` //name of file without .el extension

To this step it works fine, I find those when I press M-x column-marker and I can use it.
My problem begins when I want to use it everytime i open emacs and I found that I could use something similar to this:

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))`

Which in my case I am typing:

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\'" . column-marker))` //I want to enable it for all  .something files

But... when doing that, there is an error when opening emacs and it starts with default setup.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried many ways and none work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always *post the error message* you see. That helps others help you.
2. `C-h f auto-mode-alist` tells you that the functions you use in it must implement ***major modes***.  `column-marker` is not a major-mode function.  It is *not even a function*; it is a file.
3. What you need to do, for each mode where you want some function in file `column-marker.el` to be invoked, is to put that function on the major-mode hook for that function. For example:

```
   (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode (lambda () (interactive) (column-marker-1 80))
```

And lo and behold, what does the `Commentary` in file `column-marker.el` tell you?

```
;; Installation: Place this file on your load path, and put this in
;; your init file (`.emacs'):
;;
;; (require 'column-marker)
;;
;; Other init file suggestions (examples):
;;
;; ;; Highlight column 80 in foo mode.
;; (add-hook 'foo-mode-hook (lambda () (interactive) (column-marker-1 80)))
```

Couldn't be clearer.  Provided you actually read it.

Seriously, a minimum of investigation is in order, before you post a question to StackOverflow. You should do a Google search, open `README` files and read them, and so on --- ***first***. And in the case of Emacs questions, IMHO, you should *ask Emacs first* (e.g. `C-h v auto-mode-alist`).

According to the rules of S.O. posting, not doing preliminary simple research is even grounds for closing a question.  So do not be surprised if this question gets closed or downvoted.

Comment: I have done research, I have been through many forums, even other posts of S.O, examples and I have done many tries and none works. That's why I am asking. Also I do not know anything about elisp
What I am looking for is to execute that column-marker.el, and another .el file everytime I open emacs, and by typing (require 'column-marker) does not happen anything

Comment: For `(require 'column-marker)` to load the library, the library needs to be in your `load-path`. Do `C-h v load-path`. Emacs will help you, but you need to ask it. And if you use a 3rd-party library, such as `column-marker.el`, then you should first open it in Emacs and see what its `Commentary` says about how to use it. Anyway, hopefully my answer helps.